# comboseekbar java.lang.NullPointerException initDotsCoordinates?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, seekbar

I am trying to implement [this](https://github.com/karabaralex/android-comboseekbar) custom seekbar.

I added the comboseekbar with these steps:

- Right-click on the project
- Properties
- Android
- Add
- select "android-comboseekbar-master"
- OK
- OK

This is the xml layout file:

```
<com.infteh.comboseekbar.ComboSeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekbar" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:color="#000"
    app:textSize="12sp"
    app:multiline="false"
    />
```

And the java class:

```
private ComboSeekBar segmentedSeekbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    ....
    List<String> seekbarlist = Arrays.asList("A","B","C","D","E");
    segmentedSeekbar = new ComboSeekBar(this);       
    segmentedSeekbar.setAdapter(seekbarlist);
    ....
 }
```

After running the app on my device, I get this error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(2751): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(2751): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.salehjavaprograms.timetraveler/com.salehjavaprograms.timetraveler.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(2751):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2114)
E/AndroidRuntime(2751):     at  android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
E/AndroidRuntime(2751):     at  android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
E/AndroidRuntime(2751):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
E/AndroidRuntime(2751):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(2751):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(2751):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
E/AndroidRuntime(2751):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(2751):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(2751):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
E/AndroidRuntime(2751):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
E/AndroidRuntime(2751):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(2751): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(2751):     at com.infteh.comboseekbar.ComboSeekBar.initDotsCoordinates(ComboSeekBar.java:189)
E/AndroidRuntime(2751):     at com.infteh.comboseekbar.ComboSeekBar.setAdapter(ComboSeekBar.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(2751):     at com.salehjavaprograms.timetraveler.Main.onCreate(Main.java:69)
E/AndroidRuntime(2751):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5203)
E/AndroidRuntime(2751):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
E/AndroidRuntime(2751):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2078)
E/AndroidRuntime(2751):     ... 11 more
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to call `setThumb()` on the seekbar first. The code assumes `mThumb` is not null and `mThumb` is normally only initialized in the two-arg constructor `ComboSeekBar(Context,AttributeSet)` but not in the one-arg constructor `ComboSeekBar(Context)` you're using.

Comment: How to make `AttributeSet`?

Comment: The platform calls that constructor when you inflate the view from an XML layout.

Comment: Hi @laalto can you tell how to get the selected step-value from this android-comboseekbar-master library.I asked a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28084069/how-to-get-the-step-value-selected-in-android-comboseekbar-master