# How to get the step value selected in android-comboseekbar-master

Tags: android, seekbar

I created a comboseekbar using the library [android-comboseekbar-master](https://github.com/karabaralex/android-comboseekbar). And i implemented the xml and code

```
<com.infteh.comboseekbar.ComboSeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        app:multiline="false"
        app:textSize="12sp"
        app:color="#124578" />
```

In the java code

```
ComboSeekBar mSeekBar;


mSeekBar = (ComboSeekBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
        List<String> seekBarStep = Arrays.asList("1", "5", "15", "25", "50",
                "100");
        mSeekBar.setAdapter(seekBarStep);
```

Now i have set the step-value[1,5,15...], but how can i get the step-value when the user drags and selects each in the seekbar..

[image]

Comment: Have you found any better sloution, than the accepted one?

Comment: no! and i think this library has some others issues too. A light warning before using it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked into the library . I don't think there is an option for that. Although there is a close work around,look at my code, if you find this suitable use it, otherwise you can edit the library.

```
mSeekBar.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
     int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    toast(position + "");
    switch (position) {
    case 0:

    //do something here
     break;
    case 1:
    //do something here
     break;
    case 2:
     //do something here
     break;
    case 3:
    //do something here

     break;
    case 4:
     //do something here
     break;
    case 5:
     //do something here
     break;
    }

   }
  });
```

Comment: how to reduce size of deselected dot ? Please give some suggestion

Answer (score 0):

ComboSeekBar extends Seekbar, so I think something like this should works:

```
mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        // progress is your value
    }
    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar p_seekBar) {}
    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar p_seekBar) {}
});
```

Comment: if you use this we will get the progress on the seekbar.. but i want the stepvalue selected for the seekbar..[1,5,15...]

Comment: Well, apparently the ComboSeekBar don't have getter on 'Dot'. May be you should add it or you can also create an associative table.

Comment: ya sierra i will have to write the code myself..in the library

Comment: @Sierra : how to change text color only not seekbar color ?

Comment: how to reduce size of deselected dot ? Please give some suggestion